# Buscar por palavra levando em consideração relação entre 3 tabelas

Tags: mysql

Estou montando um sistema de busca para um guia empresarial e na hora de buscar só estou conseguindo buscar uma palavra especifica em uma tabela, por exemmplo: pizza. Mas o ideal seria ver se existe uma empresa chamada "pizza" ou se alguma que não tenha "pizza" no nome faz parte da categoria "pizzaria", por exemplo, e trazer ela.

Essa é a estrutura que estou usando para relacionar uma empresa com as categorias:

```
| empresa    |
|------------|
| id_empresa |
| nome       |
```

---

```
| categoria    |
|--------------|
| id_categoria |
| nome         |
```

---

```
| categoria_empresa    |
|----------------------|
| id_categoria_empresa |
| id_empresa           |
| id_categoria         |
```

Essa é a busca que estou fazendo:

```
SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE nome LIKE %"pizza"%
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour] você pode votar em tudo no site, além de aceitar uma resposta em perguntas sias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar as condições todas no `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
   empresa.nome, categoria.nome
FROM
   categoria_empresa
   INNER JOIN categoria ON categoria.id_categoria = categoria_empresa.id_categoria
   INNER JOIN empresa   ON empresa.id_empresa     = categoria_empresa.id_empresa
WHERE
   categoria.nome LIKE "%pizza%" OR empresa.nome LIKE "%pizza%"
```

Ps: o importante aqui é o `WHERE` conter todas as condições válidas. O `JOIN` mais adequado só depende de como vai lidar com as duplicidades.

### Retornando apenas uma linha por empresa:

Se for para retornar apenas uma empresa para várias categorias, pode fazer desta forma:

```
SELECT
   empresa.nome, GROUP_CONCAT( categoria.nome ) AS categorias
FROM
   empresa
   LEFT JOIN categoria_empresa ON empresa.id_empresa     = categoria_empresa.id_empresa
   LEFT JOIN categoria         ON categoria.id_categoria = categoria_empresa.id_categoria
WHERE
   categoria.nome LIKE "%pizza%" OR empresa.nome LIKE "%pizza%"
GROUP BY
   empresa.id_empresa
```

Neste caso, pode remover o `GROUP_CONCAT( categoria.nome ) AS categorias`. Está aí apenas para complementar os resultados e facilitar o *debug*.

E para contar os registros, para paginação:

```
SELECT
   COUNT( DISTINCT empresa.id_empresa )
FROM
   empresa
   LEFT JOIN categoria_empresa ON empresa.id_empresa     = categoria_empresa.id_empresa
   LEFT JOIN categoria         ON categoria.id_categoria = categoria_empresa.id_categoria
WHERE
   categoria.nome LIKE "%pizza%" OR empresa.nome LIKE "%pizza%"
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado pela paciência!